# How to hide React-Error-Boundary console errors in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-error-boundary

From the react docs on Error Boundaries:

> React 16 prints all errors that occurred during rendering to the
> console in development, even if the application accidentally swallows
> them.

Due to the above I am getting loads of unnecessary console errors when running my tests. Is it possible to hide these in Jest, without mocking/spying on console.error?

Answer (score 0):

Right.. Keeping the test output clean is always a good idea.
Without mocking and spying - no idea but this is my version of mocking spying.

In this case there are two steps. One is quite obvious: to filter the console output.
In the test initialization file, which is something like this:

```
"jest": {
"setupFilesAfterEnv": [
  "<rootDir>/jest/setupTests.js"
],
```

There is my code for errors and warnings filtering.

```
const warningPatterns = [
    /componentWillReceiveProps/,
    /The `css` function is deprecated/
];

const errorPatterns = [
    /Should be caught by ErrorBoundary/,
]

global.console = {
    ...global.console,
    warn: (...args) => {
        if (warningPatterns.some(pattern => args.some(line => 
            pattern.test(line)))) {
                return;
            }
        originalWarn(...args);
    },
    error: (...args) => {
        const canSkip = args.some(line => {
            return errorPatterns.some(pattern => {
                return pattern.test(line?.message || line);
            });
        });
        if (canSkip) {
            return;
        }
        originalError(...args);
     }
}
```

And then if you have JSDOM you have to mock the virtual console. I'd prefer to do this in the test cause you might not have too many Boundary tests.

```
it('should catch Errors', () => {
    const virtualConsole = window._virtualConsole;
    const originalEmit = virtualConsole.emit;
    const emit = jest.spyOn(virtualConsole, 'emit');
    emit.mockImplementation(function (type, error) {
        // you may skip the type check
        if (type === 'jsdomError' && error.detail.message === 'Should be caught by ErrorBoundary') {
            return;
        }
        return originalEmit.call(this, type, error);
    });

    const { getByText } = render(() => throw new Error('Should be caught by ErrorBoundary'));
    expect(getByText('Should be caught by ErrorBoundary').toBeInTheDocument();
    emit.mockRestore();
});
```